# Working with SQL Server and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have created a database using SQL Server 2014 Express and I would like to add it to my ASP.NET MVC project.

The only thing I succeeded is to add the the database from the SQL Server to the Visual Studio Server Explorer (but not in the project solution)

How do I do that? And after I'll add it, how can should I use with the models?

EDIT:
After FabioG's answer I have created my database like the article says.
For my project I need to use queries, I haven't understand how can I use queries with the EF. 
How can I use it ?

Comment: [ASP.NET Data Access Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178359%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Database First using MVC 5](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a very broad question to answer.
A good starting point is to follow [Getting Started with Entity Framework Database First using MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database) to understand how it all works

lets say the connection string to your entities has the name `TestEntities` where you have a table `Clients` in the database to get all the clients:

**using Link**

```
TestEntities myEntities = new TestEntities();
Clients myClients = myEntities.Clients.ToList();
```

**using Raw SQL Query**

```
using (var context = new TestEntities()) 
{ 
    var myClients = context.Clients.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Clients").ToList(); 
}
```

get a better undestanding of using Raw Queries [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: Does entity framework allows to create relationships and use queries ?

Comment: Entity Framework allows you to query using LINQ or SQL directly using `SqlQuery` method

Comment: And what about relationships between tables ?

Comment: and yes it allows you to have relationships between tables

Comment: OK, Thank you I'll start reading!

Comment: I have finished reading the Article and it is really good. I have understood how to use a database with the EF, but the thing I didn't understood is how I can use queries ?

Comment: How do I add Users system using a table of users I created ?

Comment: that's a completely different question, search for `How to Create a custom Authentication Provider` and you should find a lot of info on that matter

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide which data access framework you are going to use. Typically a connection string is put in web.config and the framework can be used to initialize the connection using that information. I'd advise you to look into a beginners Entity Framework tutorial and start from there.

Comment: I am working on this school project, and I have got some requirements. I need to manage relationships between tables and use queries.